# celery cannot find active tasks (locally and on Heroku)

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku, celery

I am trying to deploy an app on Heroku and I am using Celery and Redis to manage background tasks. I currently have a background task that collects data via FTP and puts it in the database. I also have a loading page that periodically refreshes until the task completes. However, I cannot retrieve the list of active tasks (inspect from celery.task.control returns None). I tried running this locally, and I can see that Celery receives the task (in the terminal). I can also see that Celery connects to Redis at the correct port during startup.

I have tried reinstalling several libraries, and ensuring that all variables in the settings.py file were set properly. I also tried checking the value of os.environ['REDIS_URL'], and it is correct.

relevant code from settings.py

```
CACHES = {
    "default": {
         "BACKEND": "redis_cache.RedisCache",
         "LOCATION": os.environ['REDIS_URL'],
    }
}


CELERY_BROKER_URL = os.environ['REDIS_URL']
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = os.environ['REDIS_URL']
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

celery.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'genome.settings')
os.environ.setdefault('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379/0')
app = Celery('genome_app')

app.conf.update(BROKER_URL=os.environ['REDIS_URL'],
                CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=os.environ['REDIS_URL'])

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

(in the app's views.py)

from celery.task.control import inspect

...

```
i = inspect()
active_tasks = list(i.active().values())[0]
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'values'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been having the same problem for a while now. It seems though that the devs are aware of it (https://github.com/celery/kombu/issues/1081). I have found that by trying to force it to install an older version of kombu (4.5.0 seems to now work for me) it works again for the time being.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have fixed it (locally at least). You have no idea how much anxiety this has been causing me!

Comment: Same, I was worried I had irreparably broken something! This seems to work as a solution, hopefully later versions of kombu won't have this problem too

Comment: I noticed that it still fails on Heroku. I changed requirements.txt to keep Kombu at version 4.5.0, but the problem persists. Everything seems to work on my machine. Any thoughts?

Comment: Im not familiar with Heroku, I apologise, so I can only suggest what has worked in my Dockerfile. The exact command I have used in it: RUN pip install --no-cache-dir "kombu==4.5.0" --force-reinstall

Answer (score 1):

```
from celery.task.control import inspect
i = inspect()
dictfile = i.active()

details={}
properties=[]
```

> if you want to get the args,taskid as new dict

```
for dictele in dictfile:
    for dictloop in dictfile[dictele]:
        jobid=dictloop['args']
        taskid= dictloop['id']
        jobid=jobid.replace("('","")
        jobid=jobid.replace("',)",'')
        details["jobid"]=jobid
        details["taskid"]=taskid
        properties.append(details)
print(properties)
```

> You can create your own task manager list by using above details.